# php multidimensional array get data

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need some help getting data from a multidimensional array in PHP. This array is filled with questions, and answers to those questions. Each question can have multiple answers, but the number of answers is different for most questions. This is the var_dump of it:

```
object(CommandResponse)#3 (3) 
{ 
    ["success"]=> bool(true) 
    ["message"]=> string(6) "Got it" 
    ["value"]=> array(2) 
    { 
       [0]=> array(3) 
       { 
           ["questionId"]=> string(2) "25" 
           ["question"]=> string(9) "Question 1" 
           ["answers"]=> array(2) 
           { 
               [0]=> array(2) 
               { 
                   ["answerId"]=> string(1) "1" 
                   ["answer"]=> string(9) "Answer 1" 
               } 
               [1]=> array(2) 
               { 
                  ["answerId"]=> string(2) "18" 
                  ["answer"]=> string(22) "Answer 2 for question 1" 
               }
         }
    } 
    [1]=> array(3) 
    { 
        ["questionId"]=> string(2) "26" 
        ["question"]=> string(9) "Question 2" 
        ["answers"]=> array(1) 
        { 
            [0]=> array(2) 
            { 
                ["answerId"]=> string(2) "17" 
                ["answer"]=> string(9) "Answer 2" 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

I would like to get something like this from it:

```
Question 1
  Answer 1
  Answer 2
Question 2
  Answer 1
  Answer 2
```

So far I've tried:

Get the question like this: `print $myArray->value[0]['question'];`
Get the first answer like this: `print $myArray->value[0]['anwsers'][0]['answer'];`

I've also tried to loop it in some foreach loop, but I'm not getting anything good from it.

```
foreach ($myArray->value as $key => $value)
{
    print $value['question'].' - ';
    print $value['answers'][0]['answer'].'<br />';
}
```

Comment: and you tried? where is your code?

Comment: Why not use a loop within a loop? First (upper) loop is for questions, second inner loop is for answers of that question .. ?

Comment: Just btw: I don't support that this question was closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume data is provided in the variable `$object`.

```
// Assign questions array to $questions
$questions = $object->value;

// Loop through questions
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($questions as $q) {
    echo '<li>' . $q['question'];

    // Loop through answers
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($q['answers'] as $a) {
        echo '<li>' . $a['answer'] . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Should output the desired

- Question 1

  - Answer 1
  - Answer 2
- Question 2

  - Answer 1
  - Answer 2

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm getting this `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in` since `$q` is not an object, but an array

Comment: Yes, sorry. I mixed that up. I've corrected it in the answer.

Comment: Perfect. And don't apologize, you've helped me a lot :)